# What is the halachic status of a bathroom on a job site?

Tags: halacha, employment, bathroom

Those who work in trades can often find themselves in a clients home (residential) where the toilet has been removed so work can be done. I, personally, listen to Torah Audio. I am aware it is forbidden to think thoughts of kedusha, Torah, etc. in a bathroom.

But if the toilet has been removed, is it now muttar to act regularly? Does there have to be a certain amount of time between removal and casual behavior (speaking, thinking Torah, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather complex question. I recommend gleaning what you can from [this great article](http://web.stevens.edu/golem/llevine/areivim/halacha_modern_plumbing.pdf) on the subject matter, and discussing this with a good rav. I will, *bli neder* try to do this with my rav. If possible, edit my answer afterwards. I shall summarize the article's main points.

The source of not allowing Torah thoughts, reciting shema, etc, originates from the verse Deuteronomy 23:15:

> כִּי֩ יְהוָ֨ה אֱלֹהֶ֜יךָ מִתְהַלֵּ֣ךְ ׀ בְּקֶ֣רֶב מַחֲנֶ֗ךָ
>   לְהַצִּֽילְךָ֙ וְלָתֵ֤ת אֹיְבֶ֙יךָ֙ לְפָנֶ֔יךָ **וְהָיָ֥ה מַחֲנֶ֖יךָ
>   קָד֑וֹשׁ** וְלֹֽא־יִרְאֶ֤ה בְךָ֙ עֶרְוַ֣ת דָּבָ֔ר וְשָׁ֖ב מֵאַחֲרֶֽיךָ׃
>   )
>
> For the LORD thy God walketh in the midst of thy camp, to deliver
>   thee, and to give up thine enemies before thee; **therefore shall thy
>   camp be holy**; that He see no unseemly thing in thee, and turn away
>   from thee.

Making the camp "holy", in this case, means distancing oneself from צואה - feces. (See the verses preceding the one that I cited to understand why.)

Thus, the concern is dealing with a permanent *bet hakiseh* - a room designated for use of relieving oneself. According to most opinions, one may not think Torah thoughts in a permanent *bet hakiseh* even if there is no excrement present there.

The flip side of the problem is whether today's modern "bathrooms" fit the Talmudic definition of *bet hakiseh* since excrement is flushed down and is rarely present.

That's the part of the discussion you need to read and discuss further with a rav.

Comment: Additionally, since the "toilet has been removed" the room can no longer be used as a *bet hakiseh* thus the question is does it still have the original status?

Comment: @sabbahillel a valid question. My thinking is that in the discussion, above, it says that a "permanent" *bet hakiseh* may not be used even when there is no excrement present. I infer from that, that it is the room status that determines its prohibition, and not the presence of excrement or even a toilet. Logically, then, the temporary removable of the toilet still designates that space as a *bet hakiseh*, unless that room will be transformed into some other type of room. I don't think that's what the OP implies. Therefore, it seems that the only question relates to today's bathrooms.